# Should I ask a new question if I have doubts/confusion about the answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171638/inheritance-and-public-private-methods/33171717#comment54151476_33171717) question where the OP is asking for some inheritance concept. Here is the overview:

> **One.java**
>
> ```
> public class One {
>
>   private void run() {
>       System.out.println("one");
>   }
>
>   public void start() {
>       this.run();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Two.java**
>
> ```
> public class Two extends One {
>   public void run() {
>       System.out.println("two");
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> **Main.java**
>
> ```
> public class Main {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       Two t = new Two();
>       t.start();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Output: one
>
> But if I declare `public` the run method in One class I get: two.

One of user answered it and the OP accepted it. Part of the answer:

> The run method in Two will not be overriding the private method in
>   One, because it is private and inaccessible to any class outside One.

But I had some doubts about that. `t` contains object of `Two` but `Two` does not contain `start()` so it it uses `One's` start method which has a body `this.run()`. Here `this` is current calling object `Two's` object it's like `new Two().run()` so why didn't it display `two` rather than `one`?

The above problem are my doubts.   I already tried to resolve my doubts by posting [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171638/inheritance-and-public-private-methods/33171717#comment54151476_33171717) but the answerer didn't reply.  So what should I do in this case? Should I create a new question or not? I want to clear up my confusion about this, but I don't want to create duplicate question.

Comment: Looks like the answerer replied to you.  In general, give an answerer some time; they may have other things they need to address before they get a chance to reply here again.

Comment: @Makoto It was not actually the answerer but you are correct I cant force someone to reply to my comment anyway thanks for the help

Comment: You should probably read some books to learn the basics.

Comment: @Will I tried though but I keeps on forgetting the concepts again and again I am so frustrated with myself

Comment: @codegasmer If you're forgetting things then you should be looking them up again, not asking people to look it up for you because you can't be bothered to look it up again.

Comment: @Servy my SO experience say that you have to research before asking thats what I did and I cant find anything I know there would be some source some I found which dint clear my doubts and some I dint found  so I asked the answerer to help me clear my doubts. If the case you are saying  research research and research exits then the SO would never exist.

Comment: @codegasmer 1. You apparently had no trouble finding information on it before, you just said you kept forgetting the concepts, why could you find it earlier and not now?  2. There's *tons* of information on this topic, all over the place.  There's simply no way that you could say that you can't find information on this topic.  SO is here to *create content for people to find in their research*, not to repeat widely accessible information for people who can't be bothered to search Google to get an answer.  It's been SO's mission from day 1.

Comment: Sorry. If you *keeps on forgetting the concepts again and again*, someone else explaining them again isn't going to help. Dig out your books, and read and study the material as many times as you need to until you have them memorized well enough you won't forget them again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Should I ask a new question if I have doubts/confusion about the answer?

#### The General Case

The answer in the general case is ***maybe***, but that's not the *first* thing you should do. Neither is posting a comment to the answerer.

The first thing you should do is *look for an answer to your question* — in the standard reference material, in tutorials, in books on the subject, on Stack Overflow, elsewhere on the 'net, etc.

If and only if you've looked *hard* and not found relevant explanations that you could understand, then you might consider posting a question saying what you don't understand and outlining what you've read about it, and specifically what it is about the explanations you've read that you still don't understand.

#### This Specific Case

No, you shouldn't. Any basic tutorial on Java inheritance will explain why you can call `start` on `t`, usually with diagrams and in detail. There are hundreds if not thousands if not hundreds of thousands of Java inheritance tutorials. Work through as many of them as you need to until you understand it. If you get through several of them and still don't understand it, then you are clearly not going to understand it from a written source, you'll need to look for someone who can mentor you one-on-one. A question about it on SO is not going to help, and SO is already well-stocked with Java inheritance questions.

Comment: I really like your answer - the way you separated it. Other than what the OP is asking about regarding the Java question, the question itself is absolutely valid. Unfortunately folks in the comments section submitted themselves to judging the content first. +1 and cheers!

Comment: The `If and only if` is best part and thats what my aim was for asking a question.